# SVG в chrome и safari разных размеров

Tags: javascript, html, svg, safari

Вывожу SVG на экран с помощью D3js
В хроме все ок (картинка 1), а в сафари появляются непонятные отступы (картинка 2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.html

```html
 <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>electric</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <script src="js/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
      <svg id="electric"></svg>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

main.js

```js
var mySVG = d3.select("#electric").append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "js/energyCircleAES.svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
```

energyCircleAES.svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#005F8D" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```